# Searching document from different Farm

Tags: search-results, enterprise-search

Is it possible that Farm A can access or search the documents that reside in Farm B? If yes, what should be the setup or topology?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you have two options:

1. Use the already configured search index of Farm A (search federation)
2. Crawl Farm A from farm B

You can get more information about configuration here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219577.aspx#Section12